# delimiting blocks of igbinary data

Tags: php, memcached, igbinary

I am stashing chunks of log data in memcache to later throw into a database. On each request to the server I save an array of data using memcached::append(), using newlines to delimit the chunks. A simplified version would look like this:

```
$myCache->append('log', serialize($myArray)."\n");
```

Later when I want to build may query I pull all the rows out of the database and unserialize each one:

```
$dataToInsert = explode("\n", $myCache->get('log'));
$dataToInsert = array_map(function($row) {
    return unserialize($row);
}, $dataToInsert);
```

This works fine with the built-in serialize() and unserialize(), but I'd like to take advantage of igbinary's obvious strengths - size and speed. Unfortunately when I substitute the igbinary versions of the functions, I get errors.

It appears that the igbinary-serialized data can contain "\n" characters, so when I explode the stashed data it creates partial rows that of course fail.

Is there a delimiter that I can use besides newline to separate the blocks of igbinary data, or are igbinary and append() fundamentally incompatible?

Comment: You could try an underscore `_`, just because it naturally isn't a delimiter so may work... not tested and not done it before but probs worth a try.

Comment: I was a little imprecise when I said the binary data contains newline characters; since it's binary it doesn't have characters at all. But explode() will interpret any `0A` as a newline. I guess my question boils down to, 'Is there any byte combination that will not be in the igbinary data that I can explode on? Or perhaps a method besides explode() to use to retrieve the discrete data blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`igbinary`](https://github.com/igbinary/igbinary/blob/master/igbinary.php) stores [binary data as-is](https://github.com/igbinary/igbinary/blob/master/igbinary.c#L1631), there is no guarantee of any character being available for use: you can serialize a string or integer containing any byte, any character.

[`memcached`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.memcached.php) supports adding, removing, and replacing data, and updating strings.

Two ways to keep the logged data out of memory and in memcached until the SQL query come to mind:

- use multiple keys: `'log1'`, ..., `'logN'` and keep track of `N`.
- reserve a character for yourself by escaping the binary output of the serialization (and unescaping before deserialization).

The reservation could be done like this:

```
str_replace( "\n", "\n1", $data ) . "\n0"
```

This will make sure that every time there a `\n` in the output, 
it is followed by either a `0` or a `1`.

I'm not replacing `\n` with `\n\n` because this won't work well if `$data` starts or ends with `\n`.

So:

```
$myCache->append('log', str_replace("\n", "\n1", igbinary_serialize($myArray)."\n0");
```

Splitting the data is then done using `\n0`, and the `\n1` is unescaped back to `\n`:

```
$dataToInsert = explode("\n0", $myCache->get('log'));
$dataToInsert = array_map(function($row) {
    return igbinary_unserialize(str_replace("\n1", "\n", $row));
}, $dataToInsert);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! I had started to write code to length-prefix each blob of binary data, but this feels nicer.

Comment: That would probably be faster and more efficient. I think your solution is the best answer :-)